# I want to show that $sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n.x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ by showing $R_n(x)\rightarrow0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

I tried something like that:
For $R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$  when tried to take the limit for $c=0$ I get;
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n+1)(x^{2n})(x^{n+1})}{(2n+1!)}$ (Should i look it in two cases when z=c and z=x ? since for $x>c$ wlog $z\in[c,x]$ ) After that the limit gets the form;
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{(2n!)}$ and then i am unable to evaluate it.
After that i examined the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}R_n(x)$ when i applied the ratio test i get;
$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{3n+4}}{(2n+2)!}.\frac{2n!}{x^{3n+1}}$
= $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^3}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}=0$ (since x=k for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$) which shows us the series is convergent by the Ratio test.
then $R_n(x)\rightarrow0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$ since its convergent. After that can I conclude
$sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n.x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x)=\sin(x)$. It is known $f(x)=P_{2n+1}(x)+R_{2n+1}(x)$, where $P_{2n+1}$ is the $(2n+1)$-th degree Taylor Polynomial of $f$ (let's say centered at $0$) and $$R_{2n+1}(x)=\dfrac{f^{(2n+2)}(z_n)x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!},$$ for some $z_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Note that, since derivatives of sine are, up to a sign, sine or cosine, $|f^{(2n+2)}(z_n)|\leq 1 \space \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So $$|R_{2n+1}(x)|\leq\left|\dfrac{f^{(2n+2)}(z_n)x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}\right|\leq \dfrac{|x|^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}$$

Calling $a_n=\dfrac{|x|^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}$ and applying the ratio test, we get
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{|x|^2(2n+2)!}{(2n+4)!}=\dfrac{|x|^2}{(2n+4)(2n+3)}\to 0<1,$$ so $R_{2n+1}(x)\to 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$\sin(x)=f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} P_{2n+1}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you explain the less or equal sign is it just meant to show that they are the same or something else?

Comment: Which $\le$ sign?

Comment: between $|R_{2n+1}(x)|$ and $\frac{f^{2n+2}(z_n)x^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}$

Comment: I proved the right member goes to $0$, and thus the first one goes to $0$ too, so the series is exactly equal to $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Oh okey got it thank you very much